# PG query to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a query in PG like

```
select * from companies as c left outer join assets as a on c.id = attachable_id
order by attachable_id
```

Please anybody help me to convert it into rails.

I have 2 model :
1. Company
2. Asset polymorphic model
Relation: `company has_on asset as :attachable`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be try this

```
Company.joins('left outer join assets on companies.id = assets.attachable_id').order('assets.attachable_id')
```

Comment: Is it possible to write using rails only instead of left outer join.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is to use eager loading like this

```
Company.includes(:asset).order(:assets => :attachable_id)
```

includes apply left outer join

Comment: ArgumentError: Direction should be :asc or :desc

Comment: Order is by default asc